# Prove Sylow's 1st theorem

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, group-isomorphism

**General Idea:**

Assuming Sylow's 2 Theorem Holds, Prove the 1st Sylow's Theorem.

**Mathematically written:**

if both are true:

1. G is a finite Group
2. Given such G, and prime number p, All Sylow p-subgroups are conjugate to each other

then G **has** a Sylow p-subgroup

**My effort in trying to solve the problem:**

- I took the group $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and showed it has a Sylow p-subgroup (denote $|A| = p^{\frac{|G|^2-|G|}{2}}$). (where $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the field of p elements)
- Then I showed That a for any finite G, exist a bijective homeomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow GL_{|G|}(\mathbb{F}_p)$
- So if (hypothetically) G has a p-group $H\le G$ then $\phi (H) \subseteq GL_{|G|}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is a p-subgroup as well.
- Since $|G|=n=p^m*k$ for some k and a maximal m, And Since for any $m \le \frac{|G|^2-|G|}{2}$ exist a p-subgroup $B \le A$ with $|B|=p^m$.... there might be a way of showing that B(which exists!) is conjugated to a subgroup of $\phi(G)$
- And By the bijectivity of $\phi$ we will conclude G has a Sylow p-subgroup.

I don't know how to complete the missing part, And would appreciate any help.
thanks.

Comment: Induct dividing into case with center trivial and not trivial.

Comment: You proved you can embed $\;G\;$ in $\;GL_n(\Bbb F_p)\;$ ?! May I ask how, why and what for, if you want to prove Sylow - 1 ? And how come you think you can use Sylow - 2 if you haven't yet proved Sylow - 1 ? It doesn't seem to make sense to know/use all Sylow $\;p$-  subgroups are conjugate if you haven't *yet* proved there's *at least* one such subgroup.

Comment: How: Each finite group is isomorphic to a symmetry group, since the left multiplication gG is a symmetry, now given a base to the vector space F^n - each symmetry can be represented as a Matrix in $GL_n(F_p)$

Comment: Why: Because I know $GL_n(F_p)$ has a p-sylow subgroup, using conjugation I think I will be able to prove what I need...

Comment: Ok...I guess. Yet, if you cannot prove $\;G\;$ is embedded as a *normal* subgroup of the other group, I cannot see how knowing the linear group has Sylow subgroups will help you...not to mention the proof path seems to me very messy. Have you checked *any* group theory book? Any decent one has this theorem and its proof, not to mention scores of sites in the net.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Sure - I have seen and read many proofs of that theorem, However my professor insisted that I can prove the theorem this way... And this is me trying to do so =]

Comment: Ok, so basically you want to prove that if a group has a Sylow $\;p$- subgroup, then any subgroup also has a Sylow $\;p$- subgroup, right?

Comment: Not exactly,
(1) any finite G can be embedded into $GL_n(F_p)$, for some n
(2) $GL_n(F_p)$ has a p-Sylow group

from (1), I can conclude that any p-subgroup of G will be embedded
as a p-subgroup of $GL_n(F_p)$, which is probabely (Sylow 2 theorem) conjugate to some 
subgroup of the p-Sylow group mentioned in (2), hence, since "embedded" means "endomorphism exists" 
then a subgroup of G is a p-Sylow group.

Sure. It is far from being a proof... but that's the direction...

Comment: Ok, I'm a little dizzy now, and "any" $\;p$- sbgp. of $\;G\;$ is embedded in some sbgp. of the Sylow $\;p$ - sbgp. of the linear group still wouldn't give us the existence of a Sylow subgroup in $\;G\;$ ...but **still** : wouldn't what I asked in my last comment be enough?